# Ticketing/tracking system with Subversion integration?

Tags: svn, bug-tracking, ticket-system

My company uses StarTeam for source control and CR management, but I would really like to switch to Subversion for source control.  For those of you that know ClearQuest and ClearCase, StarTeam has the ability to create tickets, which can later be associated with code changes.

Are there any similar products that integrate nicely with Subversion (preferably free, but I'm not necessarily against the idea of a commercial app)?  I played around with [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) a while back, but I wasn't overly impressed with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) integrates well, with a little effort, with Subversion.

Using [Bamboo](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/) together with Subversion and [Jira](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) can help integrate your whole release management cycle - See [A good strategy for implementing a versioning system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262953/a-good-strategy-for-implementing-a-versioning-system)

Answer (score 17):

I installed [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/) a week ago. It's quite similar to Trac but written in ruby on rails and with a better theme and with some nice ajax features (right clicking issues brings up an menu where you can change a bunch of things for that specific issue.) It integrates perfectly with Subversion and you can configure it to react to keywords (issues) in a svn-commit and connect those commits to a specific issue ID.

I'm happy with it so far!

Answer (score 4):

Looking at DZone it appears that [assembla](http://www.assembla.com/about) may fit your needs.  I haven't used it myself but it does integrate Subversion, Tickets and project management into one package.

Answer (score 4):

[FogBugz](http://fogbugz.com) also integrates with SVN, although it is not free.

Answer (score 4):

I'm also using Trac for several projects but I'm in the process of switching to Redmine.

Redmine handles multiple projects and sub-projects right out of the box and overall seems "nicer" than Trac.

Both have integration with subversion so it's a matter of determine the features you really need and the backend language you might already have available (Trac runs on Python, Redmine on Ruby on Rails).

Answer (score 2):

I just set up this combination:

- Subversion hosted on DreamHost (my domain)
- Fogbugz OnDemand - startup edition (free for 2 users only)
- Fogbugs <--> Subversion integration - FogBugz have ready post-commit hook scripts, you just have to put it into right place in your Subversion repository

It lets me add Fogbugz case number through Tortoise SVN and then I can see code changes from FogBugz.

Comment: Can you provide some details on how did you configure Subversion hosted on DreamHost to talk to FogBugz On Demand? I have a similar setup, but can't figure out where/how to place those files within the Subversion repository...

Comment: I'm having the same problem. the post-commit hook is in the right place with the right permissions. TortoiseSVN is capturing the bug id.  WebSVN is correctly reporting the details of everything, but i still can't see the commits from FogBugz.

Answer (score 2):

We use Redmine & Beanstalk at my company, and we're happy with them so far.

We evaluated Trac, Bugzilla, Mantis, Lighthouse and Redmine (FogBugz wasn't an option due to the incredibly high price), and decided that we like Redmine the best.

Answer (score 1):

All the leading bug tracking systems integrate with Subversion so that the Subversion revisions can be associated with the issue.

[BugTracker.NET](http://ifdefined.com/bugtrackernet.html) (free)
FogBugz (commercial)
Jira (commercial)
Mantis (free)
RedMine (free)
Trac (free)

A question to ask:
Do you want to host it or have it hosted for you?   If you want it hosted for you, then add to the list:
Lighthouse (commercial)
Assembla (commercial)

You can also find hosted solutions for FogBugz, Jira, and Trac.

Or do you prefer to run the app in-house, and maybe even customize the code?  Then go with a free open source alternative that's built on a technology you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

Our [Bitnami](http://bitnami.org) project website provides free one-click installers for a number of open source projects that include integration with Subversion and all the dependencies that are needed to run (Ruby on Rails in the case of Redmine, Python in the case of Trac and so on). The installers are self-contained (they won't touch your system) and take literally minutes to install (or uninstall) so you can easily "test-drive" Redmine, Mantis, Trac, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Redmine rules.

Answer (score 0):

At work we use redmine and are very pleased with it...

Integrating it with subversion is really a no brainer...

Comment: But why?
I've worked with SVN+Redmine and I must say (with TortoiseSVN client) it's a solid solution.
Everything just fits together.

One of my project members swears on "Git" being the best source control.
And some have worked with "Jira" but how does SVN/Redmine outrun these? (Except for being free when you host it yourself)

I had some arguments: "Redmine can't work with SCRUM like planning" and "Redmine doesn't work with task/issues in your IDE" but I found out there are plugins for these. But some project control services would be able to deal with this natively?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the killer deal for me it's:

Assembla Private SVN Repository (free as in free beer)
Private Redmine installation on shared hosting. (cheap... as in cheap beer)

You can create as many svn repos in assembla as you want (really it's cool), connect them with a new Redmine Project, and pure sweetness awaits you.

Answer (score 0):

Gemini integrates very well - www.countersoft.com